# How to add a key value pair to an array of objects in javascript with multiple value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, keyvaluepair

I am able to have an object like this

```
var obj = {key1: value1, key2: value2};
```

but i need an object having multiple value how can i achieve it?
for example

```
var obj = {key1:{ value1,value2}, key2: {value3,value4,value5}};
```

Comment: `var obj = {key1:[ value1,value2], key2:[value3,value4,value5]};`?

Comment: i want an object where a key belong multiple values. can you please explain if you know how to. Little more description if possible . Thank you in advance

Comment: `key1:[ value1,value2]` is a key/value pair. The value is an array containing 2 values/elements.

Answer (score 0):

An object can have properties. And the property is implementation of key value pair in javascript. If you want to have keys in an object, you need to put value for each key.

In example of yours,

```
var obj = {key1:{ value1,value2}, key2: {value3,value4,value5}};
```

sholud be

```
var obj = {
           key1:{ value1:null, value2:null }, 
           key2: {value3:null, value4: null, value5: null}
           };
```

so that, you can the directly access key in obj like obj.key1.value1 Additionally you can get keys Object.keys(obj); => ['key1', 'key2'] and Object.keys(obj.key1); => ['value1', 'value2']